# Writing struct to .dat file

Tags: c

Code

```
struct Student
{
unsigned int ID;
char name[256];
int FileLocLeft;
int FileLocRight;
int FileLocParent;
};

void main()
{
Student CurStudent;

FILE* fp = fopen("d:\\students.bat", "w");
if(fp == NULL)
{
    printf("File not found\n");
}
else
{
    fseek(fp,0,SEEK_SET);
    CurStudent.FileLocLeft = 0;
    CurStudent.FileLocParent = 0;
    CurStudent.FileLocRight = 0;
    CurStudent.ID = 0;
    CurStudent.name = "Root";
    fwrite(CurStudent,sizeof(Student),1,fp);
}
}
```

I'm having trouble with two errors, one is I cannot assign "Root" (const char[15]) to name (char[256]) and when using fwrite I get "cannot conver parameter 1 from 'Student' to 'const void'"

Comment: Don't write `void main()`; it returns an `int`.  Unless you're using C99 or C11, you need to explicitly add `return 0;` to the end of `main()`.

Comment: Also, you should check that the data was written successfully.  It is crucial that you know if the data file is clean or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't assign to an array like that in C and `fwrite` expects a pointer, you can't pass a struct. How about:

```
strcpy(CurStudent.name, "Root");
fwrite(&CurStudent, sizeof(CurStudent), 1, fp);
       ^
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Strings are no more than `char` arrays. There are special functions in C that start with `str` and help dealing with these.
2. Get the address of the struct variable, `fwrite` expects a pointer to the data.